# Why is this angularjs code not working?

Tags: angularjs

Everybody else's fiddle is working, I based my code on theirs but for some reason it is not working.

http://jsfiddle.net/prarg2zg/1/

I am seeing the curly brackets which usually disappear when angular kicks in.

HTML

```
<div ng-controller="MyCtrl">
    <table>
        <thead>
            <th>Name</th>
            <th>Age</th>
        </thead>
        <tr ng-repeat="person in people">
            <td>{{name}}</td>
            <td>{{age}}</td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</div>
```

JS

```
var myApp = angular.module('myApp', []);

function MyCtrl($scope) {
    $scope.people = [{
        name: "test",
        age: 18
    }, {
        name: "test2",
        age: 18
    }, {
        name: "Test1",
        age: 18
    }];
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Two things:

```
<div ng-app="myApp">
    <div ng-controller="MyCtrl">
        <table>
            <thead>
                <th>Name</th>
                <th>Age</th>
            </thead>
            <tr ng-repeat="person in people">
                <td>{{person.name}}</td>
                <td>{{person.age}}</td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </div>
</div>
```

Missing `ng-app`

And not using `person.name`, `person.age`

Updated fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/KyleMuir/prarg2zg/4/

Answer (score 2):

Name and age are not in scope, but each `person` is. Pull the properties off of person like you've structured in your controller:

```
<div ng-controller="MyCtrl">
    <table>
        <thead>
            <th>Name</th>
            <th>Age</th>
        </thead>
        <tr ng-repeat="person in people">
            <td>{{person.name}}</td>
            <td>{{person.age}}</td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</div>
```

You also need to register your controller to your app:

```
var myApp = angular.module('myApp', []);



function MyCtrl($scope) {
    $scope.people = [{
        name: "test",
        age: 18
    }, {
        name: "test2",
        age: 18
    }, {
        name: "Test1",
        age: 18
    }];
}

myApp.controller('MyCtrl', ['$scope', MyCtrl]);
```

Working in a fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/prarg2zg/5/

Comment: Good point about registering the controller - weird how I haven't done it in my fiddle and angular somehow wires it up.